# Input fields are covered by the keyboard

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose

Whenever a user clicks on an input field, it is covered by the keyboard and blocks the user from seeing what's being typed. Is there a workaround, similar to React Native's KeyboardAvoidingView?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Use this line in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
    android:name=".activities.LoginActivity" />
```